# C++ how to delete a structure that contains std::string. klocwork reports dynamic memory stored string is lost?

Tags: c++, klocwork

I have a following piece of code and klocwork server is throwing **dynamic memory stored in '&pData->Key' is lost** when no argument is passed. i.e., if argc is not equal to 3.

```
typedef struct
{
    std::string Key;
    std::string Value;
}KEYVALPAIR;

std::vector<KEYVALPAIR*> gData;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    KEYVALPAIR* pData = new KEYVALPAIR;

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        pData->Key = argv[1];
        pData->Value = argv[2];
        gData.push_back(pData);
    }
}
```

I cannot delete pData after the if condition because gData is containing pData memory when if condition is true. Can I delete pData in the else condition?

Comment: Use smart pointers, or avoid raw dynamic allocation. There is no reason to allocate with `new` in your sample.

Comment: Even if you use `delete` in the `else` condition, you'll still have a memory leak.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is not written by me. I dont want to change any approach here. Just need to fix klocwork issue.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik we are deleting the vector in some uninitialize call. So it is taken care.

Comment: If you don't need `pData` when the condition is false, create it inside that block.